# How can I create a HTML email in Marketing Cloud using Content Builder?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, html, content-builder

From what I see online, after I click on `Create > Email Message` I should have an option called `HTML Email` in the dropdown box. However, I only see `Template`, `Text Only`, and `Existing Email`. How do I go about creating an email from HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to have it enabled in your roles and permissions or contact support to enable if you don't see it in the drop down. See image below:

[image: create HTML]

Comment: Yep that's what I'm missing. Do you know what permission this would be?

Comment: Give yourself Administration and Marketing Cloud Administration if you can. Log out and log back in. If that doesn't work, you'll have to contact support to enable it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Admins can enable optional Email Studio feature **"HTML Paste"** in Marketing Cloud Setup.

This feature is available after December 5, 2019.

1. In the app switcher, hover over your name and click *Setup*.
2. In *Setup*, search for *Email Optional Features*.
3. Enable the feature ***HTML Paste***

You can also enable other features like

- Double Opt-In
- From Name Dropdown of Users
- List item
- Send Throttling
- CC and BCC Emails
- Impression Tracking
- Text Only Email